# Dygraphs display year only date value

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am developing a bar graph to display a yearly aggregated value compared to a series of other yearly values.  The values are of total water consumption for a year compared to the previous year and so on.  I can't figure out how to format my date field in my CSV for a single yearly value.  Assuming it must be something like 20130101, how do I customise the x axis labl to just show 2013  2012  2011 etc?

**CSV**

```
Date,Litres 
2012,42047 
2013,18604.5
```

**Code**

```
g4 = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("year"),
                 "192.168.252.30/monitoring/data_water_year.php",
                 {legend: 'always', 
                  title: 'Yearly Water Usage', 
                  xlabel: 'Date', 
                  ylabel: 'Litres', 
                  includeZero: true, 
                  animatedZooms: true, 
                  drawXGrid: false, 
                  plotter: barChartPlotter} 
);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far? This will help users answer your question more easily.

Comment: No problems.  Here is my CSV.  
    Date,Litres  
    2012,42047  
    2013,18604.5  
  
    Here is the code:  
      g4 = new Dygraph(
              document.getElementById("year"),"http://192.168.252.30/monitoring/data_water_year.php",{  
                legend: 'always',  
                title: 'Yearly Water Usage',  
                xlabel: 'Date',  
                ylabel: 'Litres',  
                includeZero: true,  
                animatedZooms: true,  
                drawXGrid: false,  
                plotter: barChartPlotter  
              }  
          );

Answer (score 7):

You want to set the axisLabelFormatter option for the x-axis to a function that only outputs the year. Possibly the valueFormatter option as well. See
http://dygraphs.com/options.html#axisLabelFormatter and http://dygraphs.com/tests/value-axis-formatters.html for inspiration.

Your code will wind up looking something like this:

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axes: {
    x: {
      axisLabelFormatter: function(d) { return d.getFullYear() },
      valueFormatter: function(ms) { return new Date(ms).getFullYear() }
    }
  }
});
```